# How to determine distinct subsets of an original set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let's say I have a distinct set of *n* integers(could be unordered). I want to determine the number of distinct subsets of size *m*, where *m* <= *n*. How would I determine that?

Comment: Have a look: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: Hi Alex. A and welcome on MSE. If you would like to improve your chances to receive an answer, I suggest you to show what you know and what have you tried to solve your question. This is not a solve-my-exercise-please-forum: a bit of effort is required